# Can I directly write in a socket in POCO Reactive Server instead of using WritableNotification?

Tags: poco-libraries

I've implemented a reactive tcp server using POCO SocketReactor. Why should I write data in a socket only on WritableNotification? Can I directly write data in a socket without adding a WritableNotification event handler?